# How much group theory is required before undertaking an introductory course on Galois Theory?

Tags: soft-question, learning

How much knowledge of group theory is needed in order to begin Galois Theory? Which topics are most relevant?

Comment: Depends on how far you want to go. But for sure you need to know about normal subgroups and symmetry groups. 
Anyway I'd suggest that you take a course on abstract algebra first, since the basic concepts show up over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Galois Theory books are self-explanatory, but you need to familiarize yourself with concepts as [solvable groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group) (this relates to equations being solvable by radicals), [simple groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_group). Also [Sylow theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems) helps a lot. In addition, knowledge of rings and fields is necessary.

By the way, Ian Stewart's book [Galois Theory](http://math.illinoisstate.edu/schebol/teaching/407-14-files/Stewart-galois_theory.pdf) makes a very nice read.

Answer (score 0):

Some elementary: definitions and examples of groups (of small orders and especially $S_n,A_n$), normal subgroups, cyclic and abelian groups, quotient groups, isomorphism theorem.

[These of these terminologies enter in the (two) main theorems of Galois; examples are needed to know just to understand what is going on].

Comment: now a days, this subject is much developed in many directions; but, the points I said are sufficient to know original theory of Galois.